# Bind to property of parent from an explicit enumerable in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Not sure if this is possible. I have an observable collection "OptionsList" with simple objects that have a "Name" and "IsEnabled" property.

Theres a menu that looks like

```
Configuration
  |--Option1
  |--Option2
  |--Option3
       |--Enabled
```

The first sub menu "Option1,Option2,Option3" bind correctly but then from within the  I try to access those items from the first sub menu and bind to their data context but i cant seem to access them via RelativeSource for some reason.

```
<MenuItem Header="Configuration">
  <MenuItem Header="Service" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionsList}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
          <Setter.Value>
            <x:Array Type="MenuItem">
              <MenuItem Header="Enabled" IsCheckable="True" 
                        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=DataContext}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
             </x:Array>
           </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
       </Style>
     </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
   </MenuItem>
 </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsChecked` is bound with wrong Path. The implicit source of the `Binding` here is already a `DataContext` which is bound to the DataContext of the parent MenuItem. So with the Path `DataContext.IsEnabled` - it will actually look for `DataContext.DataContext.IsEnabled` - of course that cannot be resolved.

You can simply remove the `DataContext.`:

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}"
```

Another problem is the `DataContext` will auto flow down the child MenuItem, so you don't need to set the `DataContext` for the inner MenuItems, which actually does not work (I've tried it and somehow the `RelativeSource` binding does not work - it's not some kind of disconnected visual tree - because the DataContext is flown down OK - so it is very strange in this case):

```
<MenuItem Header="Enabled" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

Here is a safer approach in which we use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Note that the `ItemsSource` is set to a dummy array with 1 element. Inside the `ItemTemplate` we will use a Binding walking up to the parent element for the `IsChecked` property

```
<MenuItem Header="Service" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionsList}">
   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
           <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                     <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                         <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
                             <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                         </x:Array>
                     </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                     <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                              <TextBlock Text="Enabled"/>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                     <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                         <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" 
                                    Value="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                         </Style>
                     </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>                       
                  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>
   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I tried this but still had no success. I updated my sample to reflect your change. Good catch though

Comment: @Thatoneguy see my edit, the problem is you explicitly set the `DataContext` based on `RelativeSource` binding - ***which fails*** (this case is very strange because normally if `RelativeSource` Binding fails, the DataContext won't flow down but in this case it ***does*** flow down OK).

Comment: @kingking the problem is probably not that the binding isn't working. It's more that it only works once, even with your proposed corrections. Eg. If there are 2 options you will see both of them and you can toggle them. But when you open option one submenu, then open option two and then go back to option one, the enable menu will not show any text and will not work anymore....

Comment: @MarkusGilli don't say ***probably***, you may actually mean the Binding should work. But actually per my test if you include that line of `DataContext=...` it will never work. There is some hidden problem on your side I'm not aware of so it's hard to debug this. In fact I ***never*** set `ItemsSource` to a set of controls, `ItemsSource` should always be set to a set of ***data items***.

Comment: I missed your comment about the 'flow down' of the data context and I made that adjustment and it works now with the side effect of the empty box when you have multiple items. I wanted to skip the route of making new data items for the options as there is only 1 (for now). It looks like i'll have to go the route of just adding the data model for each of the sub options. Was trying to take a shortcut and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the sub items are empty? so why you also said ***it works now***?

Comment: I have the problem @MarkusGili mentioned. If I have multiple items in OptionsList and open and toggle the IsEnabled  sub menuItem on OptionsList[0] then open OptionsList[1] and go back to open OptionsList[0] the sub menuItem will be blank with bindings set

Comment: @Thatoneguy actually you don't need a sub-model in this case. You can just set an array of dummy objects (such as an array of int) for `ItemsSource`. Then you provide an `ItemTemplate` for the sub menu item. There you can set `IsChecked` to a Binding looking up the parent MenuItem OK. There will be no shared controls issue. For the `IsCheckable` property, it can be set in Style targeting the sub menu items. You can even use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in this case.

Comment: @Thatoneguy just added code using `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as an example. The idea here is we don't set controls to `ItemsSource`, we need some dummy objects. They are called dummy because we don't use data associated with them, we use the data from the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

I think the item display doesn't work because of some kind of reuse of the MenuItems in WPF (Not sure whether this is a bug in MenuItem). Playing around with `x:Shared="False"` didn't fixed it.

There is a different approach to achieve your goal:

1. Create a helper class that is a child of your option class and provide one instance of this helper as child of the option.
2. Bind in XAML to this helper class

Here is some code that shows in detail how to do:

**XAML:**

```
<MenuItem Header="Service" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionsList}">
  <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
      <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ToggleItem}" />
      <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
          </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

**C#**

```
public class OptionHelper
{
  private readonly Option owner;

  public OptionHelper(Option owner)
  {
    this.owner = owner;
  }

  public bool IsEnabled
  {
    get { return this.owner.IsEnabled; }
    set { this.owner.IsEnabled = value; }
  }
}

public class Option : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<OptionHelper> ToggleItem { get; private set;  }

  public Option(string name, bool isEnabled)
  {
    this.ToggleItem = new ObservableCollection<OptionHelper>() { new OptionHelper(this) };
    this.name = name;
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
  }

  // your code here...
}
```

I know this is not the perfect solution but it works... Wonder if someone find a solution without the helper.

Comment: This is indeed not perfect but this is how i actually got it to work for now. I made the "ToggleItem" just a list of Option as well and passed in 'this' as the only item